# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: filename

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper, hibernate-criteria, hibernateexception

I am using Hibernate `Criteria` to get values from column `filename` in my table `contaque_recording_log`.

But when I'm getting the result, it throws an exception

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: filename of: com.contaque.hibernateTableMappings.contaque_recording_log

My table bean is:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="contaque_recording_log")
public class contaque_recording_log implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1111222233334404L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="logId", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private Integer logId;

    @Column(name="userName", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="ext", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String ext;

    @Column(name="phoneNumber", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="callerId", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String callerId;

    @Column(name="fileName", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String fileName;


    @Column(name="campName", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String campName;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="eventDate", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private Date eventDate;

    @Column(name="disposition", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String disposition;

    @Column(name="duration", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String duration;

    @Column(name="calltype", insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false)
    private String calltype;

    public Date getEventDate() {
        return eventDate;
    }

    public void setEventDate(Date eventDate) {
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
    }

    public String getCallerId() {
        return callerId;
    }

    public void setCallerId(String callerId) {
        this.callerId = callerId;
    }

    public String getExt() {
        return ext;
    }

    public void setExt(String ext) {
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Integer getLogId() {
        return logId;
    }

    public void setLogId(Integer logId) {
        this.logId = logId;
    }

    public String getCampName() {
        return campName;
    }

    public void setCampName(String campName) {
        this.campName = campName;
    }

    public String getDisposition() {
        return disposition;
    }

    public void setDisposition(String disposition) {
        this.disposition = disposition;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getCalltype() {
        return calltype;
    }

    public void setCalltype(String calltype) {
        this.calltype = calltype;
    }
}
```

MY hibernateUtil class from where I'm getting hibernate-session:

```
public enum HibernateUtilSpice {
    INSTANCE;
    public static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    private synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){

        if(sessionFactory == null){
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.addAnnotatedClass(contaque_recording_log.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(contaque_servers.class);
            config.configure();

            //get the properties from Hibernate configuration file
            Properties configProperties = config.getProperties();
            ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegisteryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegisteryBuilder.applySettings(configProperties).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession(){
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
}
```

My method where I'm getting the data from table:

```
public String getFileName() {

    try{
        hibernateSession = HibernateUtilSpice.INSTANCE.getSession();
        Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(contaque_recording_log.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("campname", "spice"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("disposition", "WN"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("filename"));
        List list = criteria.list();
        for (Object object : list) {
            System.out.println("List obj: " + object);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        hibernateSession.flush();
        hibernateSession.close();
    }
    return filename;
}
```

If I print the `criteria.toString()`, the O/P is:

```
CriteriaImpl(com.contaque.hibernateTableMappings.contaque_recording_log:this[][campname=spice, disposition=WN]filename)
```

where am I going wrong, how do I get the data from my Table?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Hibernate queries are case sensitive with property names (because they end up relying on getter/setter methods on the `@Entity`).

Make sure you refer to the property as `fileName` in the Criteria query, not `filename`.

Specifically, Hibernate will call the getter method of the `filename` property when executing that Criteria query, so it will look for a method called `getFilename()`. But the property is called `FileName` and the getter `getFileName()`.

So, change the projection like so:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("fileName"));
```

Comment: Had this problem. MY table had a column named `fk_mycolumn`, i mapped it using `name="fk_mycolumn" `, but in my DAO i was trying to query it `fk_myColumn`, with the upper case "C".

Comment: I had the same issue and issue was both getter and setter were missing !!

Comment: This helped me figure out a problem with ordering - property name was empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar kind of issue, but then resolved it by changing the parameters/arguments in the query, which weren't correctly mapped. I was using referenced table in the query, and the issue was the parameter to which it was referring via the query was invalid. So upon correcting the same, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error occurred because I was passing wrong value in Pageable to backend. The cause was wrong name of the `matSortActive` property in an Angular `.html` file.

```
<mat-table matSort matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc" matSortActive="name" [dataSource]="this.dataSource">
```